# MFC project without exe file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I did a project on visual studio mfc based in c++. It has GUI. i wanted to use its exe file in other computer, so that exe file will automatically starts whenever that computer is powered on.

Inshort i didnot want to open that exe file by myself on the computer. iT should be automatically executed.

What should you guys suggest ? Thanks

Comment: If you talk about WINDOWS, create a windows service and start your exe using that service.

Comment: do i need to create windows service sepeartely ? and then implement my mfc program without GUI ? or else. kindly please explain your answer. i am at beginner level, so it will be so nice of you, thanks

Comment: As you said your application is MFC GUI, so you need to create a separate windows service to start your MFC GUI application. That's one way

Or you can set your MFC GUI application in Windows configuration setting, Go to Documents & Settings > Username > Start Menu > Programs > Startup - File > New > Shortcut. Browse to the .exe file you want to run and follow the wizard through.